How to correctly write requests to the Telegram API?
the library I'm using doesn't have a wrapper around some of the telegram methods and I'm trying to write them myself. The problem is that I don't understand how to use the telegram documentation.
For example, I'm trying to access this method.
So, I go to postman and try to create a post request to this address:
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token of my bot>/stats.getBroadcastStats

Of course, I immediately had a question about why I need a bot token if the channel from which I’m trying to get statistics is open, but these are minor things.
Next, I’m trying to specify the parameters, but I don’t understand in which format to transmit them: json or through the “?”
In any case, I get a 404 error, as I understand it is due to an incorrect address, and not to the parameters.
I would be incredibly grateful if someone could explain to me how to decipher this documentation.

You are using the wrong documentation.
https://core.telegram.org/method/ is for the TD LIB API, not the BOT variant.

You'll need to use the https://core.telegram.org/bots/api, these are useable with a bot token.

Unfortunately the Bot api does not provide such a getBroadcastStats route.

To give you an example, lets take sendMessage, argulably the most used method, you can call it like so:
https://api.telegram.org/bot85<rest-of-token>/sendMessage?chat_id=12345&text=Hello


Unfortunately I need this method, I realized that I can use it if I can log in as a bot, but I don’t understand how to do it. I already have api_id and api_hash, but I don’t understand where to send the request...
